# Reading data from gromacs file and write it to the hdf5 file format

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to read data from .gro file  line by line and want to write this to data to .h5 file format. But getting the Typeerror: `"No conversion path ford type: type('<U7')"`. I guess the data read is in the string format. I tried to convert it to the arrays using np.arrays, but it does not work. Can anyone help me how to resolve the problem? Or are there better ways to read the data?  I cannot use the `np.loadtxt` because the size of the data is around 50GB.

The format of the .gro file looks like this

```
Generated by trjconv : P/L=1/400 t=   0.00000
11214
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    2P1     aP1    2  37.45   3.92   3.96
Generated by trjconv : P/L=1/400 t=   10.00000
11214
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    2P1     aP1    2  37.45   3.92   3.96
Generated by trjconv : P/L=1/400 t=   20.00000
11214
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    2P1     aP1    2  37.45   3.92   3.96
Generated by trjconv : P/L=1/400 t=   30.00000
11214
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    2P1     aP1    2  37.45   3.92   3.96
Generated by trjconv : P/L=1/400 t=   40.00000
11214
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    2P1     aP1    2  37.45   3.92   3.96
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #5 (got 7 columns instead of 6)
    Line #6 (got 1 columns instead of 6)
    Line #9 (got 7 columns instead of 6)
    Line #10 (got 1 columns instead of 6)
    Line #13 (got 7 columns instead of 6)
    Line #14 (got 1 columns instead of 6)
    Line #17 (got 7 columns instead of 6)
    Line #18 (got 1 columns instead of 6)
```

Here is my small code:

```py
import h5py
import numpy as np
# First step is to read .gro file
f = open('pep.gro', 'r')
data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    reading = line.split()
    #print(type(reading))
    #dat = np.array(reading).astype(int)

# Next step is to write the data to .h5 file
with h5py.File('pep1.h5', 'w') as hdf:
    hdf.create_dataset('dataset1', data=reading)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by creating the HDF5 dataset with a large number of rows [`shape=(1_000_000)`], and use the `maxshape` parameter to make it extensible. Value of `maxshape=(None,)` will allow unlimited rows. I defined a simple dtype to match your data. Creating a matching dtype for different file formats can be automated if needed.

You got the Unicode error because h5py doesn't support strings as Unicode data. (NumPy creates Unicode data from strings by default.) The work around to this limitation is defining a dtype for the array in advance (using 'S#' where NumPy has "<U".) You will use this dtype when you create the dataset AND when you read the data (see below).

Next use `np.genfromtxt` to read your directly into NumPy arrays. Use `skip_header` and `max_rows` parameters to read incrementally. Include the `dtype` parameter with the dtype used to create the dataset described above.

To test the incremental read, I extended your file to 54 lines (for 3 read loops). For performance reasons, you will want to use much larger values to read 50GB (set `incr` to what you can read into memory -- start with 100_000 lines).

**Code below: (modified to skip first two lines**

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

#define a np.dtype for gro array/dataset (hard-coded for now)
gro_dt = np.dtype([('col1', 'S4'), ('col2', 'S4'), ('col3', int), 
                   ('col4', float), ('col5', float), ('col6', float)])

# Next, create an empty .h5 file with the dtype
with h5py.File('pep1.h5', 'w') as hdf:
    ds= hdf.create_dataset('dataset1', dtype=gro_dt, shape=(20,), maxshape=(None,)) 

    # Next read line 1 of .gro file
    f = open('pep.gro', 'r')
    data = f.readlines()
    ds.attrs["Source"]=data[0]
    f.close()

    # loop to read rows from 2 until end
    skip, incr, row0 = 2, 20, 0 
    read_gro = True
    while read_gro:
        arr = np.genfromtxt('pep.gro', skip_header=skip, max_rows=incr, dtype=gro_dt)
        rows = arr.shape[0]
        if rows == 0:
            read_gro = False 
        else:    
            if row0+rows > ds.shape[0] :
                ds.resize((row0+rows,))
            ds[row0:row0+rows] = arr
            skip += rows
            row0 += rows
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I really don't get what do you mean by **I extended your file to 54 lines (for 3 read loops)**. In addition to that, the code gives **Value error: Some errors were detected** $\\$

Comment: ** Line #2 (got 1 columns instead of 8)
    Line #3 (got 6 columns instead of 8)**

Comment: I only included the column data when I created my example input. Does your file include the first 2 "non-data" lines? (It wasn't clear if/how you were reading past them.) I modified my code to handle the first 2 lines. The first line looked interesting, so I added as an attribute to the dataset. Also, I worked on the loop logic so i handles odd sizes correctly. You could also get `len(data)` to size the dataset and avoid the resizing logic.

Comment: Yes it does contain 2 "non-data" lines. By  the way it works now with skip=2. I have one more issue reading .gro the file. As mentioned in the question there are the 11214 lines + header and one more line at the end of the first frame. After that the second frame starts with same header **Generated by trjconv : P/L=1/400 t=   1000**, except now the **t=1000**. Would it possible to skip them somehow?

Comment: Code modified to skip 1 set of headers. Do the headers and data repeat in the same file? If so, can I use the count on the second header line as the number of data lines to read before the next 2 header lines? If so, do you want all of the data in 1 dataset, or a separate dataset for the data after each header?

Comment: Yes they repeat in same line. The second header starts at line 11218(if count starts from 1). Every frame has 11218 lines. I want each frame in different datasets.  Total time for simulation is **10^8** and each frame updates at **2000** timesteps. Then there will be **50000** datasets. This is only for first **P/L=1/400**.  There are 399 more to go in same format. If you can provide some starting point then I will take it forward. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The procedure to read 2000 timesteps is similar, but the order of steps is different. Also, since we know the number of rows of data for each time step (from the second header line), that simplifies dataset creation. We can use that to size each dataset, and avoid creating an extensible dataset that has to be resized.

I am writing a new answer that shows how to do this. Comments about dtype and Numpy Unicode strings still apply. This code works with a test file I created that has 2 time steps. modify `n_steps=` to work with 2000 steps.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

n_steps = 2 # 2000
csv_file = 'pep2.gro'

#define a np.dtype for gro array/dataset (hard-coded for now)
gro_dt = np.dtype([('col1', 'S4'), ('col2', 'S4'), ('col3', int), 
                   ('col4', float), ('col5', float), ('col6', float)])

# Open the file for reading and
# create an empty .h5 file with the dtype above   
with open(csv_file, 'r') as f, \
     h5py.File('pep2.h5', 'w') as hdf:

    data = f.readlines()
    skip= 2

    for step in range(n_steps):
        # Read text header line for THIS time step
        header = data[skip-2]
        # get number of data rows
        no_rows = int(data[skip-1]) 
        arr = np.genfromtxt(csv_file, skip_header=skip, max_rows=no_rows, dtype=gro_dt)
        if arr.shape[0] > 0:
            # create a dataset for THIS time step
            ds= hdf.create_dataset(f'dataset_{step:04}', data=arr) 
            #create attributes for this dataset / time step
            hdr_tokens = header.split()
            ds.attrs['raw_header'] = header
            ds.attrs['Generated by'] = hdr_tokens[2]
            ds.attrs['P/L'] = hdr_tokens[4].split('=')[1]
            ds.attrs['Time'] = hdr_tokens[6]
        skip += no_rows + 3
```

Comment: Thanks! But still getting the same error! I updated the data file in the question along with the error, just to show how data look like. I guess more number of columns required to read next header.

Comment: By looking at the error it seems the whitespaces counted as columns.

Comment: The column delimiter  for genfromtxt is whitespace (by default). Do the lines that give an error have extra spaces? If so, you may need a different method to parse the data.

Comment: yes they have the extra space. Okay! I will try the other methods. Thanks for all the effort!

Comment: In an earlier comment you said "_there is one more line at the end of the first frame_" Looking at your file update, I don't see that line. Based on the comment, I read the title header ("Generated by trjconv : P/L=1/400 t=   0.00000"), then the data count (11214), then 11214 lines of data, then skip a line after that. `np.genfromtxt()` will throw an error if you don't have the extra line (because the line count is off. It will read 7 fields from the header and 1 field from the data count line. Could that be the problem? If not, please post an sample data line with extra whitespace.