# How to correct the spaces between the columns while reading a text file?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I want to read data from a text file and write it to the hdf5 format. But somehow in the middle of the data file the space between the columns vanishes. [small part of the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fbk4hxopj7xitbx/xaa?dl=0) The data looks something like this:

```
Generated by trjconv : P/L=1/400 t=   0.00000
11214
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    2P1     aP1    2  37.45   3.92   3.96
    3P2     aP2    3  18.53  -9.69   4.68
    4P2     aP2    4  55.39  74.34   4.60
    5P3     aP3    5  22.11  68.71   3.85
.
.
 9994LI     aLI 9994  24.60  41.14   5.32
 9995LI     aLI 9995  88.47  43.02   5.72
 9996LI     aLI 9996  18.98  40.60   5.56
 9997LI     aLI 9997  35.63  46.43   5.68
 9998LI     aLI 9998  33.81  52.15   5.41
 9999LI     aLI 9999  38.72  57.18   5.32
10000LI     aLI10000  29.36  47.12   5.55
10001LI     aLI10001  82.55  44.80   5.50
10002LI     aLI10002  42.52  51.00   5.19
10003LI     aLI10003  28.61  40.21   5.70
10004LI     aLI10004  38.16  42.85   5.33
Generated by trjconv : P/L=1/400 t=   1000.00
11214
    1P1     aP1    1  80.48  35.36   4.25
    2P1     aP1    2  37.45   3.92   3.96
    3P2     aP2    3  18.53  -9.69   4.68
    4P2     aP2    4  55.39  74.34   4.60
    5P3     aP3    5  22.11  68.71   3.85
.
.
 9994LI     aLI 9994  24.60  41.14   5.32
 9995LI     aLI 9995  88.47  43.02   5.72
 9996LI     aLI 9996  18.98  40.60   5.56
 9997LI     aLI 9997  35.63  46.43   5.68
 9998LI     aLI 9998  33.81  52.15   5.41
 9999LI     aLI 9999  38.72  57.18   5.32
10000LI     aLI10000  29.36  47.12   5.55
10001LI     aLI10001  82.55  44.80   5.50
10002LI     aLI10002  42.52  51.00   5.19
10003LI     aLI10003  28.61  40.21   5.70
10004LI     aLI10004  38.16  42.85   5.33
..
..
..
```

The data is a collection of frames at t=1000 and has a million frames. As you can see in the end of frame the column 2 & 3 touches each other. I want to create the space between these while reading the data. The other issue I've with the repeated headers **Generated by..**. How can I read and write them into the hdf5 file, because h5 file does not support the strings? Are there ways to add them manually? Here is the code:

```py
import h5py
import numpy as np

#define a np.dtype for gro array/dataset (hard-coded for now)
gro_dt = np.dtype([('col1', 'S4'), ('col2', 'S4'), ('col3', int), 
                   ('col4', float), ('col5', float), ('col6', float)])

# Next, create an empty .h5 file with the dtype
with h5py.File('xaa.h5', 'w') as hdf:
    ds= hdf.create_dataset('dataset1', dtype=gro_dt, shape=(20,), maxshape=(None,)) 

    # Next read line 1 of .gro file
    f = open('xaa', 'r')
    data = f.readlines()
    ds.attrs["Source"]=data[0]
    f.close()

    # loop to read rows from 2 until end
    skip, incr, row0 = 2, 20, 0 
    read_gro = True
    while read_gro:
        arr = np.genfromtxt('xaa', skip_header=skip, max_rows=incr, dtype=gro_dt)
        rows = arr.shape[0]
        if rows == 0:
            read_gro = False 
        else:    
            if row0+rows > ds.shape[0] :
                ds.resize((row0+rows,))
            ds[row0:row0+rows] = arr
            skip += rows
            row0 += rows
```

I can skip the first header, but how to deal with the coming headers? I can provide the line number of headers if someone need. The columns throws the **valueError**

```
 ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #7 (got 5 columns instead of 6)
    Line #8 (got 5 columns instead of 6)
    Line #9 (got 5 columns instead of 6)
```

Comment: The space "disappears" because there is a 5 digit integer in the third field (and the field is only 5 characters wide). So, the text in the second field `aLI` and the integer in the third field `10000` look like one value `aLI10000`. `genfromtxt` fails because it needs a delimiter. You could use readlines and slice data at field boundaries or use the `struct` package to unpack the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer updated 2021-09-09**:
Based on the request in the comments, I added 2 new methods that use `f.readline()`. One slices the line with indices, the other uses the `struct` package to unpack the fields. `struct` is supposed to be faster, but I did not see a significant difference in performance for the test file (75 time steps).

Also, I modified the code to loop with `while True:` and break at the end of the file. This avoids the need to enter the number of time steps.

This is an answer I wrote based on your problems with my answer to your previous question. (Ref: [Reading data from gromacs file and write it to the hdf5 file format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69057872/10462884). This answer uses `readlines()` to read the data into a list. (That might be a problem with your large file. If so, the solution can be modified to read line-by-line with `readline()`.) It slices the data on each line using indices aligned to the field widths. Warning: reading 50e6 lines might take awhile. Note: HDF5 supports strings (but h5py does not support NumPy Unicode strings).

**Method 1: Uses `f.readlines()` and processes list.

Gets values by slicing each line with indices:**

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

csv_file = 'xaa.txt' # data from link in question

# define a np.dtype for gro array/dataset (hard-coded for now)
gro_dt = np.dtype([('col1', 'S7'), ('col2', 'S8'), ('col3', int), 
                   ('col4', float), ('col5', float), ('col6', float)])
 
c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 = 7, 15, 20, 27, 34
# The values above are used as indices to slice line 
# into the following fields in the loop on data[]: 
# [:7], [7:15], [15:20], [20:27], [27:34], [34:]

# Open the file for reading and
# create an empty .h5 file with the dtype above   
with open(csv_file, 'r') as f, \
     h5py.File('xaa.h5', 'w') as hdf:

    data = f.readlines()
    skip = 0
    step = 0
    while True:
        # Read text header line for THIS time step
        if skip == len(data):
            print("End Of File")
            break
        else:
            header = data[skip]
            print(header)
            skip += 1
        
        # get number of data rows
        no_rows = int(data[skip]) 
        skip += 1
        arr = np.empty(shape=(no_rows,), dtype=gro_dt)
        for row, line in enumerate(data[skip:skip+no_rows]):
            arr[row]['col1'] = line[:c1].strip()            
            arr[row]['col2'] = line[c1:c2].strip()            
            arr[row]['col3'] = int(line[c2:c3])
            arr[row]['col4'] = float(line[c3:c4])
            arr[row]['col5'] = float(line[c4:c5])
            arr[row]['col6'] = float(line[c5:])
            
        if arr.shape[0] > 0:
            # create a dataset for THIS time step
            ds= hdf.create_dataset(f'dataset_{step:04}', data=arr) 
            #create attributes for this dataset / time step
            hdr_tokens = header.split()
            ds.attrs['raw_header'] = header
            ds.attrs['Generated by'] = hdr_tokens[2]
            ds.attrs['P/L'] = hdr_tokens[4].split('=')[1]
            ds.attrs['Time'] = hdr_tokens[6]
            
        # increment by rows plus footer line that follows
        skip += 1 + no_rows
```

**Method 2: Uses `f.readline()` to read line-by-line.

Gets values by slicing each line with indices:**

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

csv_file = 'xaa.txt'

#define a np.dtype for gro array/dataset (hard-coded for now)
gro_dt = np.dtype([('col1', 'S7'), ('col2', 'S8'), ('col3', int), 
                   ('col4', float), ('col5', float), ('col6', float)])

## gro_fmt=[0:7], [7:15], [15:20], [20:27], [27:34], [34:41]
c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 = 7, 15, 20, 27, 34
# Open the file for reading and
# create an empty .h5 file with the dtype above   
with open(csv_file, 'r') as f, \
     h5py.File('xaa.h5', 'w') as hdf:

    step = 0
    while True:
    # Read text header line for THIS time step
        header = f.readline()
        if not header:
            print("End Of File")
            break
        else:
            print(header)

        # get number of data rows
        no_rows = int(f.readline()) 
        arr = np.empty(shape=(no_rows,), dtype=gro_dt)
        for row in range(no_rows):
            line = f.readline()
            arr[row]['col1'] = line[:c1].strip()            
            arr[row]['col2'] = line[c1:c2].strip()            
            arr[row]['col3'] = int(line[c2:c3])
            arr[row]['col4'] = float(line[c3:c4])
            arr[row]['col5'] = float(line[c4:c5])
            arr[row]['col6'] = float(line[c5:])
            
        if arr.shape[0] > 0:
            # create a dataset for THIS time step
            ds= hdf.create_dataset(f'dataset_{step:04}', data=arr) 
            #create attributes for this dataset / time step
            print(header)
            hdr_tokens = header.split()
            ds.attrs['raw_header'] = header
            ds.attrs['Generated by'] = hdr_tokens[2]
            ds.attrs['P/L'] = hdr_tokens[4].split('=')[1]
            ds.attrs['Time'] = hdr_tokens[6]
            
        footer = f.readline()
        step += 1
```

**Method 3: Uses `f.readlines()` to read line-by-line.

Uses `struct` package to unpack values from each line:**

```
import struct
import numpy as np
import h5py

csv_file = 'xaa.txt'

fmtstring = '7s 8s 5s 7s 7s 7s'
fieldstruct = struct.Struct(fmtstring)
parse = fieldstruct.unpack_from

#define a np.dtype for gro array/dataset (hard-coded for now)
gro_dt = np.dtype([('col1', 'S7'), ('col2', 'S8'), ('col3', int), 
                   ('col4', float), ('col5', float), ('col6', float)])

with open(csv_file, 'r') as f, \
     h5py.File('xaa.h5', 'w') as hdf:
         
    step = 0
    while True:         
        header = f.readline()
        if not header:
            print("End Of File")
            break
        else:
            print(header)

        # get number of data rows
        no_rows = int(f.readline())
        arr = np.empty(shape=(no_rows,), dtype=gro_dt)
        for row in range(no_rows):
            fields = parse( f.readline().encode('utf-8') )
            arr[row]['col1'] = fields[0].strip()            
            arr[row]['col2'] = fields[1].strip()            
            arr[row]['col3'] = int(fields[2])
            arr[row]['col4'] = float(fields[3])
            arr[row]['col5'] = float(fields[4])
            arr[row]['col6'] = float(fields[5])
        if arr.shape[0] > 0:
            # create a dataset for THIS time step
            ds= hdf.create_dataset(f'dataset_{step:04}', data=arr) 
            #create attributes for this dataset / time step
            hdr_tokens = header.split()
            ds.attrs['raw_header'] = header
            ds.attrs['Generated by'] = hdr_tokens[2]
            ds.attrs['P/L'] = hdr_tokens[4].split('=')[1]
            ds.attrs['Time'] = hdr_tokens[6]
            
        footer = f.readline()
        step += 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I don't quit get few things in the code! I highlight them in the code.

Comment: Still the problem persists! The first frame is read successfully, but starting with next frame it throws the **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Generated by trjconv : P/L=1/400 t= 1000.00000\n'**

Comment: I link the small part of the file in the question in case you want to have a look!

Comment: You asked: '*What is the purpose of these slices?*' The indices were for my reference to create slices. I didn't use them. Instead, I used the c1, c2, c3 values (immediately below) to slice `line` into variables.

Comment: I think I know what is causing the problem. In your earlier post, you said you have a text (footer) line after the data lines and before the next header. But, your example file doesn't show an extra line before the next header. So, I increment as `skip += no_rows`. If you have a footer, change that line to `skip += 1 + no_rows` and it will skip the footer and start with the next header on the next loop.

Comment: Thanks! It works now :) . Would it be possible for you add the **readline()** method in the code?

Comment: 2 `readline()` methods added. Both avoid creating a large list. Method 3 (with `struct` package) might be faster reading very large files.